# Migrate AFNetworking 2.x to 3.x missing Data object to be able to Decode

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am migrating `AFNetworking` from 2.x to 3.x but I am facing an issue that I can't figure out how to fix.

With `AFNetworking 2.x` I was able to get the Data on the response and use it to Decode it into my object with something like this:

```
api.get(userListPath, parameters: parameters, success: { (operation, _) in
            guard let data = operation.responseData else {
                let localizedFailureReason = "No data"
                handler(CustomObject.failure(XError.init(xErrorWithCode: XErrorCode.xErrorServer.rawValue, localizedFailureReason: localizedFailureReason)))
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode(CustomObjectResponse.self, from: data)
                handler(CustomObjectResponse.success(response.likes))
            } catch let err {
                let responseError = ResponseError.parsing(reason: err.localizedDescription)
                Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(err)
                handler(CustomObjectResponse.failure(XError(xErrorWithCode: XErrorCode.xErrorServer.rawValue, localizedFailureReason: responseError.localizedDescription)))
                return
            }
        }, failure: { (operation, error) in
            handler(CustomObject.failure(error))
        })
```

But now, since `AFNetworking` doesn't use `NSOperation` anymore, I have no way to get the data to decode it.
I feel I am missing something key or important but I can't figure out what it is.
Any example I've seen so far for the migration (or the migration Guide even) just use the `responseObject` so then the change is not that big. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What's happening if you do `guard let data = responseObject as? Data` ? It doesn't work? I used AFNetworking previously, and I always used `responseObject`, not `operation`. If I remember correctly, if you didn't put any responseSerializer, `responseObject` should be a `(NS)Data` object, else, it if you put a JSONReponseSerializer, it should be an `(NS)Array` or a `(NS)Dictionary`. So even on the 2.x version, it should work.

Comment: @Larme Thing is, I have an AppClient that has a AFHTTPSessionManager manager where I use everywhere. I want to get the JSON response in most cases but sometimes I need the Data. This was possible before because NSOperation had the Data there.